# parsing image name from img tag with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have an `<img>` tag inside a div where i want to get the image name through javascript and regex.

Now, I successfully retrieved the `<img>` tag as a string.

```
var bigImage = $(this).find('.img-container img')
var bigImageSrc = bigImage[0].src
var regx = /g\bplaceholderdefault\.jpg?\b/g
var match = bigImageSrc.match(regx)
```

I want this expression to see if there is `placeholderdefault.jpg` in the string.

> By the way, bigImageSrc returns a valid string, as I checked it with `typeof`

Now the problem is it returns null even if `bigImageSrc`'s value is `http://localhost/yogurtbar/images/slider/placeholderdefault.jpg`

I don't get why it doesn't detect `placeholderdefault.jpg` in the string. I tried (and produced) this regular expression in [Regexr](http://regexr.com) and it works.

What am I doing wrong in my code?

Comment: `placeholderdefault.jpg` != `placeholder-default.jpg`

Comment: should there be a dash or no in the file name?

Comment: eh, removed the dashes. sorry. that wasnt correct. i have no dashes in the images. still it doesnt work.

Comment: Why are you writing `jpg?`? Do you really want to make `g` optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `g` present at the start.

```
var regx = /g\bplaceholderdefault\.jpg?\b/g;
            ^
            |
```

Since there isn't a charcater `g` exists before `p` (in placeholder), your regex fails to find a match.

correct one would be,

```
var regx = /\bplaceholderdefault\.jpg?\b/g;
```

and also, I think you want to match both `jpg` and `jpeg` formats.

```
var regx = /\bplaceholderdefault\.jpe?g\b/g;
```

Comment: what's the `g` at the start for? I just generated the code from a site, so I don't fully understand it

Answer (score 3):

There is no need of `regex`.\

You can use `indexOf`. This will run faster as compared to `regex`:

```
if (bigImageSrc.indexOf('placeholderdefault.jpg') > -1) {
    // Present
```

If you want to check it with `regex`:

```
if (/placeholderdefault\.jpg/.test(bigImageSrc)) {
    // Present
}
```

You need to escape `.`

Comment: I think you have to escape "." in regex.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way will be to get the image name using `split()`

```js
var bigImageSrc = 'http://localhost/yogurtbar/images/slider/placeholder-default.jpg';    
var filename = bigImageSrc.split("/").pop();

 console.log(filename);
 //output placeholder-default.jpg
```